# How to connect CSS and JS to HTML which is sent by Dart HttpServer?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, dart-http

I have created a Dart HttpServer which shows "HTML" code on the browser but I also want to connect "CSS" & "JS" to this HTML,
How should I do that? please help

```
HttpServer _server;
_server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port);
_server.listen((request) async {
        request.response
          ..headers.contentType = ContentType.html
          //HTML Code
          ..write('''
                     <!DOCTYPE html>
                     <html lang="en">
                       <head>
                         <meta charset="UTF-8">
                         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                         <! -- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
                         <title>Hello World</title>
                       </head>
                       <body>
                         <p>Hello WOrld</p>
                       </body>
                       <! -- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
                     </html>
                 ''');
        await request.response.close();
      }
```

PS 1: One Solution is to add CSS and JS codes in the HTML code which would work but is less efficient.

PS 2: I am using this dart code in a flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just use html tag.
2. Don't neglect every source imported by html tag is a http request. you should handle these requests. Dart HttpServer doesn't handle these.